# How do I shift the contents of a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to take the following data frame:

> ```
>      loc1        loc2          loc3
> 1     <NA> Subcortical Basal ganglia
> 2 Cortical Subcortical Basal ganglia
> 3     <NA> Subcortical          <NA>
> ```

and shift the contents to the following:

> ```
>     loc1          loc2          loc3
> 1 Subcortical Basal ganglia          <NA>
> 2    Cortical   Subcortical Basal ganglia
> 3 Subcortical          <NA>          <NA>
> ```

I've tried ifelse statements as below, but it gets too complex:

> ```
> test$loc1 <- ifelse(is.na(test$loc1) & !is.na(test$loc2), "Subcortical", "Cortical")
> test$loc2 <- ifelse(test$loc1=="Subcortical", NA, "Subcortical")
> test$loc2 <- ifelse(is.na(test$loc2) & !is.na(test$loc3), "Basal ganglia", "Subcortical")
> ```

I've also tried unite and unite_ from the tidyr package, but I can't find an elegant answer. In my research, I couldn't find this answer anywhere, but happy to be directed to one if I missed it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Maybe `t(apply(test, 1, sort, na.last = TRUE))` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg `sort` would also do the sorting on other non-NA elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` with `MARGIN=1` can be used (as showed by @David Arenburg in the comments) to loop over the rows

```
 df1[] <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])
```

Or

```
df1[] <- t( apply(df1, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
df1
#       loc1          loc2          loc3
#1 Subcortical Basal ganglia          <NA>
#2    Cortical   Subcortical Basal ganglia
#3 Subcortical          <NA>          <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(loc1 = c(NA, "Cortical", NA),
loc2 = c("Subcortical", 
"Subcortical", "Subcortical"), loc3 = c("Basal ganglia",
"Basal ganglia", NA)), .Names = c("loc1", "loc2", "loc3"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Your second suggestion worked on a large dataset. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [`naLast`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/naLast.R) function from my [GitHub-only "SOfun"](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun) package.

The usage would be:

```
library(SOfun)
naLast(df1)
#   loc1          loc2            loc3           
# 1 "Subcortical" "Basal ganglia" NA             
# 2 "Cortical"    "Subcortical"   "Basal ganglia"
# 3 "Subcortical" NA              NA
```

... or the same concept by columns instead...

```
naLast(df1, by = "col")
#   loc1       loc2          loc3           
# 1 "Cortical" "Subcortical" "Basal ganglia"
# 2 NA         "Subcortical" "Basal ganglia"
# 3 NA         "Subcortical" NA
```

Comment: Where are all the voters today?  They seem to be off somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I think something like (not tested)

```
out <- alply(dta, 1, function(x) out <- x[!is.na(x)])
```

using the 'plyr' package could work.

It looks like you're trying to do something to each row of the dataframe (call it dta), so best to treat it as an array, and act on its first margin (hence 1 as the 2nd argument). Then you want to extract, in order, each of the elements that is not NA. Is this correct?